# kivy ToggleButton : How can I trigger a method on the state changement?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is my actual code. It does what I want except when I change the `state` with a script, it doesn't give the information. It only gives the information when the change is made with a user interaction.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ToggleButton:
        id: toggle_button
        text: "click on me"
'''

class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    loading_layout = None

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        screen.ids["toggle_button"].bind(on_press=lambda instance: self.on_click(instance))

        print("I change the state and I want to be aware")
        screen.ids["toggle_button"].state = "down"
        print("on_click method isn't enough :(")

        return screen

    def on_click(self, instance):
        print("State changed !", instance.state)

ExampleApp().run()
```

Question: How can I link a function to the `state` changement and not only on the `click` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is take advantage of the `on_state` method of the `ToggleButton` class. Here is an example:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    CustomToggle:
        id: toggle_button
        text: "click on me"
'''


class CustomToggle(ToggleButton):

    def on_state(self, *args):
        print('State changed!', self.state)

    def on_press(self):
        print("Button pressed!", self.state)


class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    loading_layout = None

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        screen.ids["toggle_button"].state = "down"
        return screen


ExampleApp().run()
```

The `on_state` method is automatically bound to the `state` attribute, so that whenever the `state` is changed the function is called.

Comment: My bad, I didn't look into the good url.
I just watch this one: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.togglebutton.html
But the info was on this one: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.ToggleButtonBehavior

Thank you for the answer, this is what I was looking for (simple and logical, as we all like it !)

Comment: I'm still having a problem. Your example is good but I can't bind `on_state` as I bind `screen.ids["toggle_button"].bind(on_press=lambda instance: self.on_click(instance))
`

Comment: Try `screen.ids["toggle_button"].bind(state=lambda instance: self.on_click(instance))` whereas `on_press` is a predefined function `on_state` is not, so you'll have to bind the property and not the function (if that makes sense).

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.html Take a look at this to see what I mean

Comment: Perfect ! I have exactly what I needed, thank you !
If I understand, it's like `on_press` and `on_release` are created to be binded where `on_state` shouldn't be override ?